# Building an OID->MIB index from a PySMI script using JSON?

Tags: pysnmp

I have successfully compiled several MIBs into JSON using PySMI with JsonCodeGen and CallbackWriter (which uploads the parsed JSON to cloud storage). Now I am trying to build an index using freshly compiled JSON MIBs in combination with already-compiled JSON files.

From the documentation, it looks like I need to pass all of these files to mibCompiler.compile() function, even though most of them have already been compiled, so that I can run mibCompiler.buildIndex() after compiling.

From what I understand, I need a searcher to exclude the already-compiled JSON MIBs...is this the case? All I see in the current code are PyFileSearcher, StubSearcher, and AnyFileSearcher. I 'm not sure what to do from here to ignore my JSON files.

I'm also not sure buildIndex() will even accept JSON files as input, so I'm hoping this is the right approach.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm also not sure buildIndex() will even accept JSON files as input, so I'm hoping this is the right approach.

Actually, no! Present day PySMI compiler can only parse ASN.1 MIBs, it will fail on JSON input.

Probably the simplest solution would be to just load JSON MIBs *and* existing JSON index into Python as dicts, walk the dicts updating one another. Here is [the code](https://github.com/etingof/pysmi/blob/master/pysmi/codegen/jsondoc.py#L1015) that builds JSON index dict out of some internal objects (which carry pieces of MIB data).

From PySMI perspective, the best course of action would probably be to introduce a JSON MIB compiler which would turn JSON MIB into the abstract syntax tree from which JSON MIB index could be build...

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response - and seriously thank you (!!) for this awesome library. Would it be faster to do this approach or to try to build the index from the original MIBs? I have both available to me.

Comment: hey, my pleasure! ;-)  If you have the original ASN.1 MIBs at hand and you do not mind re-running pysmi over them - that requires virtually no effort and time, right? Or are you planning to repeat this many times what brings up the performance concerns?

Comment: It gets repeated anytime a user uploads a new MIB to the cloud. If a user uploads 12 MIBs, it will currently get repeated 12 times (not ideal, but how the cloud trigger works in AWS S3)...so I'd say performance is a strong consideration. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing: when pysmi build the index, it does not do it from scratch. Instead it **updates** the existing index not touching the stuff that's already there (unless the new MIB you are indexing redefines the items). If you feed all 12 new MIBs at once to pysmi/mibdump, it will parse them all in one shot and updates the existing index retaining the mappings that are already there. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does. And believe me, I wish I could do them all at once (I may have to research and find a way). It sounds like the MIB -> index way might be faster, since it's just an update. Thanks for the help!